# Correct metadata for VR180 video on YouTube

Tags: youtube, 3d, vr

I have a Vuze XR camera, which can capture 3D videos in 180°, and I'd like to compose a VR180 movie for YouTube by joining several clips using free tools.

I'm almost there, but my supposedly 180° video is turning out 360° with some sort of mirror image on the other side, and the video is initialized right into the stitch of the two sides, so I need to rotate it 90° to view it properly.

My process so far is:
1) capture clips
2) use Vuze VR Studio to export each clip to the default YouTube format (if I upload this one directly it shows correctly on YouTube, although I had some issues with the timeline)
3) use DaVinci Resolve to create video with several clips
4) use VR180 Creator to add metadata (from the GUI I didn't select any of the checkboxes)

Here is an example: [before the metadata](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JiR8WU80_FY) I get a normal rectangular video with left and right eyes; while [by adding metadata](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNOTPg2VVr8&feature=youtu.be) it correctly identifies as a VR video that I can move around and watch with a VR headset, but it's 360° and by default it is positioned with the edge of the 180° image on the center.

Any ideas on how I can fix this or suggestions of other free tools (Linux, Windows or Mac) that I could use to correctly edit the videos?

Comment: I'm still trying to get this to work. I was actually using spatial media to inject metadata. With VR creator the error I get is "Video dimensions must be set for v1 metadata injection".

Answer (score 0):

Google's VR180 Injector should do the trick
https://arvr.google.com/vr180/apps/

Comment: I'm still trying to figure our how to get the correct input for that, as I get the error "Video dimensions must be set for v1 metadata injection" when I try to use it.

Comment: @TylerSammy, could you perhaps expand your answer a little bit to describe how to use it? Maybe add a link to the relevant documentation page?